# Can't call blockchain function using setInterval method

Tags: javascript, setinterval, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

When I call `setInterval()` invoking blockchain function (written in solidity) it does not call it.
In the following code `checkconsensus()` calls solidity function, and it is passed to `setInterval()` of JavaScript.

```js
var func = checkconsensus;
var run = setInterval(func, 80000);

function checkconsensus(newscount, i, myVar) {
  var instance = contract.at(addr)
  var estimatedGas = 3000000;

  var txnObject = {
    from: web3.eth.coinbase,
    gas: estimatedGas
  }

  alert(instance) //it is printed
  //the following function is not called
  instance.returnallposval(newscount, txnObject, function(error, result) {
    if (!error)
      alert(result)
    else
      alert("error")
  })
}
```

Comment: Do you want to wait 1:20 minutes?

Comment: Yes ,I want to wait for  1:20 minutes

Comment: @Amira What's newscount value? Did any error appear in the browser console?

Comment: I actually had not deployed smart contract properly ,that is why  function was not called .Thank you